# Стало быть - значение

Tags: значения

> Не было никаких примет, по которым можно было предсказать появление Кондуктора, ни одной, кроме того, что ты вылез на поверхность. Ты вылез на поверхность, а стало быть, живёшь без билета.

Как лучше понять это сочетание *стало быть* в этим контексте? Никакие из предложений моего словаря не подходят мне к контексту.

Answer (score 1):

*Стало быть* = *значит*, *следовательно*. Само сочетание когда-то являлось формой прошедшего времени (перфект) от глагола *стать*, но в современном русском языке перфекта больше нет.

Answer (score 1):

СТАЛО БЫТЬ, вводное выражение и союз

1. Вводное выражение. **То же, что «следовательно, значит, выходит».** Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми.

Но, на беду, это все был народ, с которым было трудно ладить, народ торопливый, занятой или же принадлежащий свету, – стало быть, еще более занятой, нежели всякий другой, и потому нетерпеливый до крайности. Н. Гоголь, Портрет. Ты, стало быть, уже уезжаешь?

2. Союз. Синтаксические конструкции с союзом «стало быть» обособляются.

Говорю, выходи, стало быть и выходи! А. Чехов, Маска. Яков не искал реальных, осязательных последствий от своего стучания для того дела, за которое он «стоял» столь неуклонно среди глухих стен и не менее глухих к его обличениям людей; он видел «пользу» уже в самом факте «стояния» за Бога и за великого государя, стало быть поступал так «для души». В. Короленко, Яшка.

**В Вашем предложении "стало быть" - вводное выражение.**